# Why the [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation returns wrong values

Tags: iphone, uiinterfaceorientation

Hi in my application i would like to know the `statusbarorientation` value. For that i am using  `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation` method. Actually this method have to return 4 for landscape and 2 for potrait mode. But this method returning the values in opposite way. Means for landscape 2 and for potrait 4. Please let me know how to fix this issue.In `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method i am using return `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;`

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: post code what you tried ?

Comment: UIInterfaceOrientation statusBarOrientation =[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
 
    if(statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft  || statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {

Answer (score 1):

It probably happens because the UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight is assigned to UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft and UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft is assigned to UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight.

**The reason for this is that rotating the device requires rotating the content in the opposite direction.**

Starting in iOS 8, you should use the UITraitCollection and UITraitEnvironment APIs, and size class properties as used in those APIs, rather than using UIInterfaceOrientation constants or otherwise writing your app in terms of interface orientation.

Anyway, taking the orientation in this way worked for me.

```
var orientation = UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarOrientation;
switch (orientation)
{
case UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown:
// The device is in portrait mode but upside down, with the device held upright and the home button at the top.
case UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait:
// The device is in portrait mode, with the device held upright and the home button on the bottom.
case UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
// The device is in landscape mode, with the device held upright and the home button on the left side.
case UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight:
// The device is in landscape mode, with the device held upright and the home button on the right side.
case UIInterfaceOrientation.Unknown
// The orientation of the device cannot be determined.
}
```

Consider also that

> If your app has rotatable window content, however, you should not
>   arbitrarily set status-bar orientation using this method. The
>   status-bar orientation set by this method does not change if the
>   device changes orientation.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question asked.

Comment: Answer improved and extended to the new iOS 8 too. How it is now?

Comment: Thanks — I was able to understand why my app isn't working as expected. I converted my downvote to an upvote :)

Comment: Thanks to your comment I improved my answer and I hope can be more helpful for many people as possible. Thanks to you.